# Scrapy Pipelines to Seperate Folder/Files - Abstraction

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I currently finalising a Scrapy project however I have quite a lengthy `pipelines.py` file.

I noticed that in my `settings.py` the pipe lines are show as follows (trimmed down):

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
     'proj.pipelines.MutatorPipeline': 200,
     'proj.pipelines.CalculatorPipeline': 300,
     'proj.pipelines.SaveToFilePipeline': 500,
}
```

I have tried the following ways to rectify this.

1.) I created a new file/folder and tried referencing it from pipeline in the same manner.

Folder was `myPipelines/Test.py` with a class name `TestPipeline` then referenced in pipeline settings as `proj.myPipelines.Test.TestPipeline': 100,`.

This threw me errors.

I then thought I could export the module and import into my current `pipelines.py` and it would take the reference from that. I added an empty `__init__.py` in my `myPipelines` directory and then added `from myPipelines.Test import TestPipeline` but scrapy still throws an error of...

```
Raise NameError("Module '%s' doesn't define any object named '%s'" % (module, name))
exceptions.NameError: Module 'proj.pipelines' doesn't define any object named 'TestPipeline'.
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12):

When you start a scrapy project, you get a directory tree like this:

```
$ scrapy startproject multipipeline
$ tree
.
├── multipipeline
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── middlewares.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── spiders
│       ├── example.py
│       └── __init__.py
└── scrapy.cfg
```

And the generated `pipelines.py` looks like this:

```
$ cat multipipeline/pipelines.py 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html


class MultipipelinePipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

But your scrapy project can reference any Python class as item pipelines. One option is to convert the generated one-file `pipelines` module to a package within its own directory, with submodules.
Notice the `__init__.py` file inside the `pipelines/` dir:

```
$ tree
.
├── multipipeline
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── middlewares.py
│   ├── pipelines
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── one.py
│   │   ├── three.py
│   │   └── two.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── spiders
│       ├── example.py
│       └── __init__.py
└── scrapy.cfg
```

The individual modules inside the `pipelines/` dir could look like this:

```
$ cat multipipeline/pipelines/two.py 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class MyPipelineTwo(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        logger.debug(self.__class__.__name__)
        return item
```

You can read [more about packages here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the
>   directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent
>   directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally
>   hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In
>   the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can
>   also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__`
>   variable, described later.

And your `settings.py` would contain something like this:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'multipipeline.pipelines.one.MyPipelineOne': 100,
    'multipipeline.pipelines.two.MyPipelineTwo': 200,
    'multipipeline.pipelines.three.MyPipelineThree': 300,
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you! This should be marked as an answer.